# Show the linear functional relating to the solution of ODE is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is an exercise in the book by *B. Daya Reddy*.

For $f \in L^2(0, 1)$, let $u_f$ be the solution of the ODE: $u'' + u' - 2u = f$, $u(0) = u(1) = 0$. Define the functional $\ell$ by
$$
    \langle \ell, f \rangle = \int_0^1 u_f(x) dx \ \forall f \in L^2(0, 1)
$$
Show that $\ell$ is a bounded linear functional.

I have shown $\ell$ is linear, but struggle to bound $\ell$. From the ODE
$$
    u'' + u' - 2u = f, u(0) = u(1) = 0
$$
integrate from $0$ to $1$ for both side, we have
$$
    \langle \ell, f \rangle = \int_0^1 u_f(x)dx = \dfrac{u_f'(1) - u_f'(0)}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx
$$
Therefore,
$$
   \vert \langle \ell, f \rangle \vert \le \dfrac{\vert u_f'(1) - u_f'(0) \vert}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}\lVert f \rVert_2
$$
Am I on the right track ? How to bound the term $\dfrac{\vert u_f'(1) - u_f'(0) \vert}{2}$ in term of $L^2$ norm of $f$ ? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: does the MVT help?

Comment: @kipf The only way I can think of MVT for this problem is, $\vert u_f'(1) - u_f'(0) \vert = \vert u_f''(c) \vert$, for some $c \in (0, 1)$. Other than that, I don't know how

Comment: do you know about Sobolev spaces and Lax-Milgram? It tells us that the solution map $f\mapsto u_f$ from $L^2((0,1))\to H^1_0((0,1))$ is continuous, so without any further work, you can immediately bound the first line by the functional by the $L^2$-norm of $u_f$ which is bounded by a multiple of the $L^2$-norm of $f$. Otherwise, the only way I can think of is to use the explicit solution formula (I believe it’s called the technique of *variation of parameters*? Here justifying the formula for $f$ continuous is easy, but for $f\in L^2$, you need some finessing).

Comment: ok never mind, we can simply re-word parts of the argument needed to apply Lax-Milgram (setting aside the question of existence), i.e essentially an ‘energy estimate’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply your ODE by $u$ throughout, then integrate from $0$ to $1$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1u’’u +\int_0^1u’u-\int_0^12u^2&=\int_0^1fu.
\end{align}
Integrate by-parts on the first term to get $[u’u]_0^1-\int_0^1|u’|^2=-\int_0^1|u’|^2$, since $u(0)=u(1)=0$. For the second term, it can be integrated to give $\left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]_0^1=0$. Hence, rearranging gives
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\bigg(|u’|^2+ 2|u|^2\bigg)\,dx&=-\int_0^1fu\,dx\leq \int_0^1|f|^2\,dx+\int_0^1|u|^2\,dx,
\end{align}
and so rearranging gives
\begin{align}
\|u’\|_{L^2}^2+\|u\|_{L^2}^2&\leq\|f\|_{L^2}^2,\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
meaning in particular the solution map $f\mapsto u_f$ from $L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ is bounded (with operator norm at most $1$).

With this,
\begin{align}
|\langle\lambda,f\rangle|&\leq\|u_f\|_{L^1([0,1])}\leq\|u_f\|_{L^2([0,1])}\leq \|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}.
\end{align}

---

The only thing left to justify is why we are able to perform all these manipulations with the integration-by-parts and stuff, but for this, I cannot really do so without the language of Sobolev spaces.

But I guess one very weak way of saying it is that when $f\in C([0,1])$, you can write down an explicit integral formula involving exponentials and stuff, giving us an explicit formula for a $u\in C^2([0,1])$. In this case, our manipulations are completely justified, and our estimate $(*)$ showed that the map $f\mapsto u_f$ from $C([0,1])\to C^2([0,1])$, where the domain and target are equipped with the $L^2$ norm is continuous (actually even better, on the target we can use the norm $\|u\|_{H^1}:=\|u\|_{L^2}+\|u’\|_{L^2}$), and hence has a unique continuous linear extension to a map $L^2\to L^2$ (resp $L^2\to H^1_0$, where $H^1_0$ can be defined as the completion of $C^2$ or $C^{\infty}$ functions which vanish at the endpoints, using the Sobolev norm $\|\cdot\|_{H^1}$).